# "All leaves are cancelled." or "All leave is cancelled."?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

How do we use the word "leave" in a sentence? Is it ever pluralized? Is it correct to say "How many days leaves do you get per year?" or "How much leave do you get per year?"

Comment: "Leave" (in this sense) is generally a mass noun, though if 10 people had been authorized "leave" and their authorizations were cancelled it would not be improper to say "there leaves were cancelled".

Comment: (Oops!!  Actually, that *would* be improper, but "their leaves were cancelled" would not be.)

Comment: @Astralbee - It's a mass noun, just like "water".  This is why you say "all leave is cancelled".  You wouldn't say "All water are wet."

Comment: @HotLicks I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask your employer for time off work, "leave" actually means the *permission* they grant for the absence, not the absence itself. The phrase "*absent without leave*" refers to situations where someone is absent *without permission*.

"Leave", as in "leave of absence" *does* have a plural - "*leaves* of absence". From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_of_absence):

> Generally, paid **leaves** of absence are given at the request of the employer

However, the plural is not often used because the word "leave" has come to be a shortened version of the phrase "leave of absence", and is used as a mass (uncountable) noun, for example:

> - I have used all my leave for this year.
> - I have been on leave 6 times this year.
> - Everybody needs to book their leave.

As your example uses the noun "leave", the correct rendition would be:

> All leave is cancelled.

However, if you were to use the phrase "leave of absence", the correct rendition would be:

> All *leaves of absence* are cancelled.

Comment: I can't agree with the last example: I suggest "all leave of absence must be requested formally."

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you think it should be "all leave of absence"? Because that sounds completely wrong. The point I am making is that "leave" has become a replacement collective noun for "leaves of absence".

Comment: Isn't "leave of absence" a noun phrase? I have never heard this meaning of **leave** in the plural. In the example, it is unlikely that more than one absence is requested anyway. Another example is "I have used up all my leave" even when there were several absences.

Comment: @WeatherVane It isn't used often, in fact I had to look it up. My original draft of this answer was wrong, so I'm being humble here. Look it up in the dictionary, the plural of leave is *leaves*, but it is only really used in phrases like "leaves of absence". Because "leave" really means the *permission*, not the absence.

Comment: The only context in which I can imagine _leave_ being treated as countable is that of a soldier on active service - "His last two leaves have been very short ones."

Comment: Thanks for all the insights here, still find myself confused on this one. When a person is going to be absent from work for several days do we say that the person is "On leave" or "On Leaves?" My guess is to say "John Smith is on leave."